# My wifi is not showing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wireless, reboot

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3Lts, and I have the pro version activated.
My desktop has a motherboard model mag B760m mortar wifi DDR4.
And I have dual ssd drive. 1 for windows and the other for Ubuntu.
It boots automatically in Ubuntu

When I boot my PC it shows not wifi, not internet, not nothing. But if I restart it, It shows everything every time. Any body knows what the issue might be?

Comment: This looks like a Windows fast boot/startup problem making the hardware unavailable in Linux. Try keeping using that workaround, disabling those options in Windows, or upgrading to a new Ubuntu release with newer firmware